# JFreechart with minor grid lines

Tags: jfreechart, gridlines

I have produce a code for a dynamic jfreechart and I want this chart to have Major grid lines and Secondary grid lines.

Is that possible to happen with jfreechart??

Thanks in advance!!!

EDIT:

Unfortunatelly I don't use XYplot but I use TimeSeries Chart like the following:

```
JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart(
                       "Measurement",
                       "Date",
                       "Measurement",
                       dataset,
                       true,
                       true,
                       false);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using an XYPlot you can turn on the minor gridlines using:

- `XYPLot#setDomainMinorGridlinesVisible()`
- `XYPLot#setRangeMinorGridlinesVisible()`

as well as controlling the colour and line style, full details in the [documentation](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/XYPlot.html)

You are using an XYPLot, if you look at the source code for `ChartFactory#createTimeSeriesChart()` you will see that the 6th line is:

```java
XYPlot plot = new XYPlot(dataset, timeAxis, valueAxis, null);
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly I don't use XYplot but I use TimeSeries Chart like the following:                                                JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart(
"Measurement",
"Date",
"Measurement",
dataset,
true,
true,
false);

Comment: @kostaspapadopoulos I think you will find that `ChartFactory#createTimeSeriesChart()' creates an 'XYPlot'

Comment: Can you please be more specific?

Comment: [`ChartFactory#createTimeSeriesChart()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/ChartFactory.html#line.1886)

Answer (score -1):

This is the code I use:

```
 TimeSeries ts= new TimeSeries("Metrisi", Day.class);
     ts.add(new Day(day1, month1, year1), 100);
     ts.add(new Day(day2, month2, year2), 150);
     ts.add(new Day(day3, month3, year3), 250);
     ts.add(new Day(day4, month4, year4), 275);

     TimeSeriesCollection dataset = new TimeSeriesCollection();
 dataset.addSeries(ts);
 JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart(
 "Measurement",
 "Date",
 "Measurement",
 dataset,
 true,
 true,
 false);
```

As a result when I create a TimeSeriesChart I don't have the ability to create major grid lines and secondary grid lines?